# Show that $\left| A_n \right| = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} B(n - k)$ where $B(n)$ is the nth Bell number.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion, set-partition, bell-numbers

I am having some trouble solving the following problem:

Let $A_n$ be the set of set partitions of $\{1, . . . , n\}$ without any singleton blocks. Show that $$\left| A_n  \right| = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k  \binom{n}{k} B(n - k)$$ where $B(n)$ is the nth Bell number.

Here we cannot use generating functions and our professor told us to apply the principle of inclusion-exclusion. So, I let $A_S$ to be the collection of set partitions of $\{1, . . . , n\}$ where each element of $S$ is in a singleton block and start working from there but I end up with
$$\left| A_{=S}  \right| = \sum_{k=0}^{n-|s|} (-1)^k  \binom{n-|s|}{k} B(n -|s|- k)$$
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Should the first sum include the $k=0$ term? Aren't you then trying to compute $|A_{\varnothing}|$? Then $S=\varnothing$, and plugging in $|S|=0$ gives the original formula.

Comment: Hello @kevinLong  , yes it is suppose to be $k=0$, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your displayed formula is clearly wrong, since for $n=4$ the righthand side is $-11$.

The inclusion-exclusion principle says that

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_{\{k\}}\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|I|+1}\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}A_{\{k\}}\right|\\
&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|I|+1}|A_I|\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}kB(n-k)\,,
\end{align*}$$

since there are $\binom{n}k$ subsets $S$ of $[n]$ of cardinality $k$ and $B(n-k)$ partitions of $[n]\setminus S$. This is the number of ‘bad’ partitions of $[n]$, i.e., of partitions that have at least one singleton block. There are altogether $B(n)$ partitions of $[n]$, so

$$\begin{align*}
|A_n|&=B(n)-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}kB(n-k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}kB(n-k)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you @Brian M. Scott, Can you explain me how do you define $I$ in the  inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: @AlexisSandoval: In that first summation it simply ranges over all non-empty subsets of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Also, how do you get the B(n-k) in the inclusion-exclusion principle? Also, why you subtract the sum from B(n) in the last inequality?

Comment: @AlexisSandoval: If $S$ is a $k$-element subset of $[n]$, there are $B(n-k)$ partitions of $[n]\setminus S$, and there is an obvious bijection between them and partitions of $[n]$ that have a block $\{s\}$ for each $s\in S$, so there are $B(n-k)$ partitions of $[n]$ that have a block $\{s\}$ for each $s\in S$; i.e., $|A_S|=B(n-k)$. The first sum is the number of partitions of $[n]$ that you **don’t** want. There are $B(n)$ partitions of $[n]$ altogether, so the difference it the number that you **do** want.

Comment: @AlexisSandoval: You’re welcome!